# Semantic ui Form

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor, semantic-ui

For some reason `submit event` is not working for a simple form using the semantic ui package.

This is my form.

```
<form class="ui form register-form">
  <h4 class="ui dividing header">Create your AC Account</h4>
  <div class="">
    <div class="required field">
      <div class="ui icon input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui submit button register-button">Register</div>
 </form>
```

So how the submit event should look?

```
Template.example.events({
 'submit .register-button' : function() {
  console.log("submited")
  }
})
```

**NOTE:** also im truing with the form class name `.register-form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has no submit button. Only a `div` formatted as a button with the class of `submit`. You'll either need to add a click handler to the `div` or switch to an actual button.

Comment: Actually both answers are corret and bot answer help me so i dont really dont know what answer accept

Answer (score 3):

Change your template markup to include a submit button :

```
<template name="example">
  <form class="ui form register-form">
    <h4 class="ui dividing header">Create your AC Account</h4>
    <div class="">
      <div class="required field">
        <div class="ui icon input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="ui submit button register-button" type="submit">Register</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Then listen on the `submit` event on the `form` element :

```
Template.example.events({
  "submit form": function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //
    [...]
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually both answers are corret and bot answer help me so i dont really dont know what answer accept

Comment: but i think justin answer is more correct isnt? for example what happend if i have 2 forms on the same template? i will need the button not?

Comment: A submit button inside a form triggers its `submit` event, so if you have 2 forms inside the same template, assign each form an `id` and declare 2 different `submit` handlers for each form. `submit #form1` ; `submit #form2`